# Mongo aggregation - $in expression?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'd like to have a step that returns a boolean if a field is contained in an array, like:

```
$project: {
   // would return whether the field 'type' is banana or apple
  isFruit: { $type: { $in: ['apple', 'banana'] } },
},
```

But this doesn't work. Looking at the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), I see nothing around a contain test. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit convoluted, but you can do this by using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) to filter your input array to just the element (if any) that matches `type` and then comparing the result against `[]`:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        isFruit: { $ne: [[], { $filter: {
            input: ['apple', 'banana'],
            as: 'fruit',
            cond: { $eq: ['$$fruit', '$type'] }
        }}]}
    }}
])
```

Note that `$filter` was added in MongoDB 3.2.

Comment: That looks great! Any idea on possible performance drawbacks?

Comment: @Guig I'm not sure how well it will scale, you'll have to test it out in your real scenario.